# Handling null reference exception in linq

Tags: c#

Consider the following

```
var x= doc.Descendants("a").Where(p => p.Attributes["itemprop"].Value.Contains("image")).FirstOrDefault().Attributes["href"].Value;
```

Descendants might return null

Where might return null

Value might return null

Attributes might Be null
etc..

is a try catch my only option to set the variable to null with the linq syntax to avoid the null reference exception, i simply want to set the variable to null and i don't want to split it out and use multiple if statements to check?

```
try
{
  x= doc.Descendants("a").Where(p => p.Attributes["itemprop"].Value.Contains("image")).FirstOrDefault().Attributes["href"].Value;
}
catch
{
  x=null;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5753430/11683 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/11683

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Descendants can't return null` it always return `IEnumerable<T>`

`Where can't return null` it return `IEnumerable<T>`

`Attributes might Be null` yes but you can avoid using Value you can use `(string)p.Attributes["itemprop"]` instead of `p.Attributes["itemprop"].Value`

so you can write your query as:

```
string val;

var x= doc.Descendants("a")
           .Where(p => (((string)p.Attributes["itemprop"]) ?? string.Empty)
                              .Contains("image"))
           .FirstOrDefault();
if(x != null)
{
    val = (string)Attributes["href"];
}
```